# How do I rewrite a query from SQL Server to PostgeSQL?

Tags: sql-server, plpgsql

My T-SQL code is:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[test_mssql]
    (@TaskId int = NULL,
     @RootTaskId int = NULL,
     @SessionUserId int,
     @XmlParam xml = NULL,
     @OnlyOneRow bit = 0,
     @DataType varchar (20) = 'GetChilds')
AS
BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE #t (PID int, Id int, UN varchar(500))

    INSERT INTO #t (PID, Id, UN)
        SELECT osu.PID, osu.Id, u.FN 
        FROM Users u WITH (NOLOCK)
        JOIN uosu WITH (NOLOCK) ON u.UID = uosu.UID
        JOIN osu WITH (NOLOCK) ON uosu.OSUID = osu.Id
        WHERE u.IsFired_2 = 0
          AND uosu.IsPrimary = 1

    BEGIN
        SELECT PID, Id, UN 
        FROM #t
    END
END
```

I tried to rewrite it to plpgsql:

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test_plpgsql(
      IN TaskId integer = null,
      IN RootTaskId integer = null,
      IN SessionUserId integer = null,
      IN XmlParam xml = null,
      IN OnlyOneRow boolean = false,
      IN DataType varchar(20) = 'GetChilds'
    ) RETURNS TABLE (PID integer, Id integer, UN varchar(500))
    AS $$
    BEGIN
      CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE t (PID integer, Id integer, UN varchar(500));
      INSERT INTO t (PID, Id, UN)
        SELECT osu.PID, osu.Id, u.FN
        FROM Users u
        JOIN uosu ON u.UID = uosu.UID
        JOIN osu ON uosu.OSUID = osu.Id
        WHERE u.IsFired_2 = 0
    AND uosu.IsPrimary = 1;
  RETURN QUERY SELECT PID, Id, UN FROM t;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

But I have an error:

> POSITION: 178; SQL: ;
> ---> Npgsql.PostgresException: 42601: syntax error at or near "$1"

Is the error in the plpgsql script I wrote, or in the Npgsql data provider?

Answer (score 0):

[Documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql.html) is your friend :-). More in this case, because PL/pgSQL is very different than T-SQL. Good start is forgot all what you know about T-SQL. On second hand - stored procedures in Postgres (PL/pgSQL) are very similar to Oracle (PL/SQL). PL/pgSQL is almost simplified version of PL/SQL (although some part are very different still).

You should to use `RETURN QUERY` command directly:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test_plpgsql(
      IN TaskId integer = null,
      IN RootTaskId integer = null,
      IN SessionUserId integer = null,
      IN XmlParam xml = null,
      IN OnlyOneRow boolean = false,
      IN DataType varchar(20) = 'GetChilds'
    ) RETURNS TABLE (PID integer, Id integer, UN varchar(500))
    AS $$
    BEGIN
      RETURN QUERY
        SELECT osu.PID, osu.Id, u.FN
        FROM Users u
        JOIN uosu ON u.UID = uosu.UID
        JOIN osu ON uosu.OSUID = osu.Id
        WHERE u.IsFired_2 = 0
        AND uosu.IsPrimary = 1;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Maybe you use some very old version of PostgreSQL. In these versions, the PL/pgSQL identifier was preferred always and everywhere. Clause `RETURNS TABLE(PID integer, ..) defines an structure of output relation (columns of output relation), but it defines local variables too (one for any output column).

The statement `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE t (PID integer, Id integer, UN varchar(500));` uses identifier `PID`. Next statement `INSERT INTO t (PID, Id, UN)` uses identifier `PID` too. Old versions (before PostgreSQL 9.0 (2010)) replaces identifies to arguments symbols (like `$1`) everywhere (without knowledge of context). Modern versions of Postgres (last 12 years) use different mechanism, and there should not be this problem. I was able to create function from your example without any problems.